# Including a new image view inside scroll view causing error

Tags: android, android-layout

i am having a scroll view like this . There is an image view with id="@+id/but_logo_view1 inside that. I wanted to add another image view to right of that. I tried several ways. But am getting a force close error. How can I achieve the desired result. Please help

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lineartop"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dip"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:paddingRight="10dip" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/but_logo_view1"
            android:layout_width="60dip"
            android:visibility="visible"
             android:layout_height="60dip"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/camera" />

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
        android:gravity="center" >

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textView2"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:text="User Name"
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:textSize="18dip" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_signup_user"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:maxLength="10"
            android:textSize="18dip"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:hint="Name"
            android:singleLine="true"
           android:textColor="@color/black" android:gravity="center"/>

    </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            android:gravity="center" >

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textView2"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:text="Email"
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:textSize="18dip" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_signup_email"
            android:layout_width="150dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:hint="optional"
            android:padding="3dip"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="18dip"
             android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textColorHint="#858585" android:gravity="center"/>

    </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
            android:gravity="center" >

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textView2"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:text="Password"
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:textSize="18dip" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_signup_passwd"
            android:textSize="18dip"
          android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="number" android:maxLength="4"

             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
           android:textColor="@color/black"

            android:padding="3dip"
           />


    </TableRow>

             <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
            android:gravity="center" >

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textView2"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:text="Retype Password"
              android:textColor="#000000"
              android:textSize="18dip" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_signup_repasswd"
            android:textSize="18dip"
          android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="number" android:maxLength="4"

             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
           android:textColor="@color/black"

            android:padding="3dip"
           />


    </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
       <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:gravity="center" >

           <Button
               android:id="@+id/but_signup_twitter"
               android:layout_width="70dip"
               android:layout_height="70dip"
               android:background="@drawable/twitter_icon"
               android:visibility="invisible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/but_signup_login"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/sign_in_unlit" android:typeface="serif" android:layout_marginLeft="20dip" android:layout_marginRight="20dip"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/but_signup_fb"
    android:layout_width="70dip"
    android:layout_height="70dip"
    android:background="@drawable/facebook_icon" />

            </TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:gravity="center|right" >




       </TableRow>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error may be occurring because it is a LinearLayout, You could try using   instead and setting the imageview like this :

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/but_logo_view1"
        android:layout_width="60dip"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_height="60dip"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
```

You can then adjust the padding or the x-axis according to how far away you want the image to be.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the previous poster missed a word in his response, but to use 'layout_alignLeft' you need to use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout